# It was not possible to find any compatible framework version. The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core

I had a .Net Core console app built and deployed.

The project's Platform target is x86.

Target framework is .Net Core 2.2(x86).

Although .Net Core 2.2 (x86) SDK is installed, I get following error after executing the command dotnet myapp.dll in Developer Command Prompt VS2017.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
- The following versions are installed:
2.0.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
2.1.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

The .Net Core 2.2(x86) SDK was installed under path "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared", and System Environment Variables contains "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\".

Any suggestion? Thanks!

~~~Update1

Following are part of .csproj info, sorry can't show whole thing.

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: That error message sounds pretty definitive.  Just a thought, but why not try installing .NET Core 2.2 anyway?

Comment: What's the output of `dotnet --list-runtimes`? Does it include Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0?

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦ I installed .Net Core 2.2(x64), got different error "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxx'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.". My project's platform target is x86, should execute the program under .Net Core 2.2(x86). I think the problem is system did not recognize that x86 .Net Core was installed.

Comment: Aha.  Now we're getting somewhere.

Comment: can you also share your .csproj? and which assembly is it complaining about?

Comment: @Jonathon Chase, it shows Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0, which I just installed according to  Robert Harvey♦ suggestion. But it did not show .Net Core 2.2(x86) version.

Comment: @Aman B post has been updated. Thanks. I am suspecting the project file too.

Comment: @wltz thanks, I'm suspecting some nuget packages need updating. Have you tried updating the installed nuget packages?

Comment: @All my nuget packages are up to date, except 1 third-party dll. I doubt that's the issue. I find it's weird in the csproj file, the TargetFramework section only mentioned netcoreapp2.2, how could this tell it's based on Net Core x86 or x64!

Comment: Recently, after a windows update, I had to run such an install, and indeed afterwards everything worked again.

Comment: If you had any other .net version installed, maybe there is a leftover environment var DOTNET_ROOT specified, which makes your system look into the wrong path.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After searching through Microsoft's documentations, I noticed that I was missing an additional required Nugget package.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#installing-the-tools) stated:

> Before you can use the tools on a specific project, you'll need to add
> the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package to it.

This is what I did by adding the package

`$ dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

Comment: yes your answer did help me..thx a lot

Comment: this answer helped me when I was trying to use Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore !

Comment: Thanks. It did help!

Comment: Still relevant. Works with Postgresql on MacOS 12.2.1

Answer (score 18):

Some months ago a Visual Studio update broke my capability of running tests. One of the issues was exactly this error. I have the x64 version of the SDK installed but VS tests runner was attempting to use the x86 version. The fix is just changing a setting inside the Test Explorer: `Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects -> x64`.

[image]

Comment: It was on auto but didn't worked for me, i had to manually select x86. Now it is working, thanks for this quick help.

Comment: Where is this button? I can't find it on the UI

Answer (score 5):

It seem to be a known issue for .Net Core installation, [github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4350](http://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4350)

I have to uninstall all .Net Core packages, both x64 and x86, then reinstalled .Net Core x86 package. And that solved the problem.

Comment: i'm using VSCode and when i switch to x86, it won't let me debug.

Comment: @samyi I was using Visual Studio for this project. Maybe give Visual Studio a shot?

Comment: For me, I simply had to update my .NET installation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos

Comment: The `dotnet --info` command helped to understand the problem, and I just updated Visual Studio and the update also fixed the .Net 6 installation.

Answer (score 2):

This error also happened to me, and the answer I found was very easy, =>
in my solution I had two projects and a class library, the data folder was in the API project, in the case of Migration, I set the default project to the API and I got the same error, but the answer: I just set the API project as the startup project and tried again. The issue was gone.

Have fun.
Shahab Attarnejad

Answer (score 1):

Can you change .csproj to add `RunCommand` like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x86'">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x64'">$(ProgramW6432)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Maybe you need to add 2 line of `RunCommand` and update the correct path of dotnet on your laptop.

This issue happens when you are on windows 64bit and run x86 application.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've add these two lines to the section <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">, cause the platform target is x86. After rebuild and deploying, I still got the error "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly". .Net Core 2.2(x86) still not in my runtime list. I think I will get .Net Core x86 installed properly first.

Comment: it seem to be a known issue for .Net Core installation, https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4350. I have to uninstall all .Net Core packages, both x64 and x86, then reinstalled .Net Core x86 package. And that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just verified that all the projects in the solution is of same Target framework version. Once that was done, the issue was fixed.

You could view the Target framework version by right clicking a project (*.csproj) and go to properties.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error just now, it turned out that I need to run an update on Visual Studio.

Close your project window, open the **Visual Studio Installer**, and run the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue in 2022. @Khai Nguyen answer worked for me.

### HelloWorld.csproj

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I changed the `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp5.0</TargetFramework>`

to

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework>`

Since, 6.0 was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

- Visual Studio 2022 v17.3.6
- WSL with dotnet 6.0.1 (in Ubuntu) and 6.0.10 (on Windows)
- testEnvironments.json

`"Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version"`

I needed to enalbe the Remote Testing install option in the Test Options:

[image: Remote Testing Option]

Answer (score 0):

I was using `testenvironments.json` for running the unit tests, but when picking my **Ubuntu** distribution from the list

[image: testenvironments.json Ubuntu]

no tests are discovered. The Output window (Tests output) shows the following:

```
Log level is set to Informational (Default).
Connected to test environment '< Local Windows Environment >'
Test data store opened in 0,323 sec.
Connected to test environment '< Local Windows Environment >'
========== Starting test discovery ==========
========== Test discovery skipped: All test containers are up to date ==========
WSL2 environment 'Ubuntu' is starting.
Connected to test environment 'Ubuntu'
WSL2 environment 'Ubuntu' is running.
========== Starting test discovery ==========
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Testhost process for source(s) '/mnt/c/Users/user/source/repos/Project/Project.UnitTests/bin/Debug/net6.0/Project.UnitTests.dll' exited with error: You must install or update .NET to run this application.
App: /mnt/c/Users/user/source/repos/Project/Project.UnitTests/bin/Debug/net6.0/testhost.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/local/.dotnet_install/
No frameworks were found.
Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.ThrowOnTestHostExited(IEnumerable`1 sources, Boolean testHostExited)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 704,8 ms ==========
```

After restarting Visual Studio, it suggested me to install the missing runtime inside WSL:

[image: is not installed in the WSL distribution]