# It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.8' was not found

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, webapi, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to run simple .net core 2.2 api project from my visual studio 2019 instance, this error keep showing up : `The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found. It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.8' was not found` .

I've checked .net core runtimes installed on my machine which are as following :

```
C:\Windows\system32>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.26 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Here is part of .csproj file :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.9.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="LightInject" Version="6.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="LightInject.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MassTransit" Version="5.5.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.8.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Async" Version="1.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Redis.Core" Version="5.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.0.601" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController" Version="4.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
```

Any idea how to fix this annoying issue ?

Comment: `dotnet --list-runtimes` shows that you dont actually have any 2.2.x version of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` installed (even though you have the ASP bits installed). Have you tried re-installing a 2.2.x runtime?

Comment: @omajid I'm trying to do that now

Comment: After following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751769/it-was-not-possible-to-find-any-compatible-framework-version-the-specified-fram uninstalling .net core SDK and reinstalling again make the API run fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install [.net Core 2.2 sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.2)

Comment: This answer is partially correct, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751769/it-was-not-possible-to-find-any-compatible-framework-version-the-specified-fram for the complete solution