# Azure DevOps Pipeline VsBuild dont work with Azure Function v2

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, .net-standard-2.0, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to publish my app with Azure DevOps. I have on the same repo 2 Azure functions (v2 and 3), 1 web application and 2 "libraries projects" (.net Framework 4). So it's my first time with DevOps and it's really hard...

I have a problem when building. I use a VSBuild task to build all the projects at the same time. Here my yaml :

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET SDK 2.1'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '2.1.202' #I tried some others versions too
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'project.sln'
```

Here the error :

```
##[error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.29\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): Error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
```

And in the csproj of the project (Azure Function)

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Has someone an idea to make this build work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this `##[error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.29\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): Error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version` error:

Make sure your **1 web application** and **2 libraries projects** both have the same version of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29`.

References: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/199#issuecomment-665776934 , [It was not possible to find any compatible framework version. The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751769/it-was-not-possible-to-find-any-compatible-framework-version-the-specified-fram) and https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3487